# How to convert loop into stream, to this java code snippet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
 for(Fees fee : feeList) {
    if(fee.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(feeType)) {
        baseFee = fee.getAmountFee();
        break;
    }
 }
```

I wanted to know if it's possible to convert the above example to a single stream where there is a for loop.

Comment: Yes, that is quite possible. And it's not all that difficult. stream -> filter -> findFirst -> if present ...

Comment: for (ItemDO item : updateItems.getItemsDO().getItems())
how to do if loop given like this @Stultuske.

Comment: SO is not about handing you custom code. We either put you on the right path, or, if you've already tried, help you correct your code. So far, I haven't even seen you attempt to create a Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you can convert it as follows:

```
Optional<Double> optionFeeAmount = feeList
                .stream()
                .filter(fee -> feeType.equalsIgnoreCase(fee.getType()))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Fees::getAmountFee);
```

You can add `orElse(0)` at the end, if you want to return 0 as a default result. Also you can use `findAny()` if the sequence in list doesn't matter.

Comment: @lokesh598 this does already stop at the first match and return it. No need for a “break” statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, something like:

```
baseFee = feeList.stream().filter(fee -> fee.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(feeType))
            .map(Fees::getAmountFee)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(baseFee);
```

Solution explanation:

- `filter` function replace the if condition
- `map` function will replace every `Fees` with their `amountFee`
- `findFirst` function will do the same job as `break;` and will return on the first match.
- `orElse` if there is no match I kept the same `baseFee` value

The stream API (functional programming) is smart enough in performance meaning that it will not filter everything and then do the map, instead it will do it in its way, with good performance.